# Laravel prevent automatic boot() function call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having a problem with Laravel 4.2. Please, have a look in the following code:

```
Model/User.php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function($post) {
            $post->created_by = Auth::user()->id;
            $post->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });

        static::updating(function($post) {
            $post->updated_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }
}
```

Controller/UserController.php

```
$user = new User;
$user->username= 'John';
$user->password = Hash::make('123456');
$user->save();
```

Whenever I create or update a User of the **boot()** function is being called automatically. Is there any way to prevent this function to be called automatically?

Comment: What do you mean? These function are meant to run when you create or update a user. If you want to disable them just remove them or put the outside of the boot function and call them manually.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code and perhaps we can supply a better method of doing so. Stopping the `boot()` method from being called is just going to break lots of stuff.